# Connect to AWS managed redis cache, exposed by an upstream service, using kube-proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, redis-cluster, kube-proxy

I have a following scenario in the k8s cluster.

1. AWS managed redis cluster which is exposed by a upstream service called redis.
   I have opened a tunnel locally using kube-proxy.

```
curl 127.0.0.1:31997/api/v1/namespaces/intekspersistence/services/redis
{
  "kind": "Service",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "redis",
    "namespace": "intekspersistence",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/intekspersistence/services/redis",
    ...
  "spec": {
    "type": "ExternalName",
    "sessionAffinity": "None",
    "externalName": "xxx.xxx.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com"
  },
  "status": {
    "loadBalancer": {

    }
  }
```

As shown, I am able to route to the redis service locally and it's poinintg to the Actual redis host.
Now I am trying to validate and ping the redis host using the below python script.

```
from redis import Redis
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
redis = Redis(host='127.0.0.1:31997/api/v1/namespaces/intekspersistence/services/redis')

if redis.ping():
    logging.info("Connected to Redis")
```

Upon running this, It's throwing error as host not found. [Probably due to inclusion of port in the host].

```
python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    if redis.ping():
  File "/home/appsadm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1378, in ping
    return self.execute_command('PING')
  File "/home/appsadm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 898, in execute_command
    conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
  File "/home/appsadm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1192, in get_connection
    connection.connect()
  File "/home/appsadm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 563, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to 127.0.0.1:31997/api/v1/namespaces/intekspersistence/services/redis:6379. Name or service not known.
```

Is there a workaround to trim the port from host?? Or to route to the host using the above python module.

Comment: What you are accessing via curl appears to be the K8s API and not redis. The `host` arg to the redis object should be a hostname only, not a full path with port. It's very strange to see a path like that for redis (which doesn't use http).

Comment: Also, ExternalName services do not do routing. They simply tell kube-dns to override what the real DNS is. No routing involved.

Comment: But the requirement is to cover all the environments, i.e. redis hostname can't be known at build time, and i have to make sure if the cluster exists while deployment.

Comment: Personally, the way I solve that issue is I have the terraform that creates the elasticache instance also create a configmap inside the cluster that contains the connection information. I then export that configmap as env variables to the relevant pods.

Comment: While you can make ExternalName work for unecrypted redis, it will not work properly for anything that uses SSL due to hostname differences.